# отзеркалить персонажа с анимацией

Tags: c#, unity3d

При попытке отзеркалить персонажа с анимацией в `unity 2D` он не зеркалится(пустой объект - персонаж, на котором скрипт, содержит в себе много спрайтов, анимация наложена на самого персонажа). Предположительно ошибка в том что объект зеркалится измением `scale` на `-1`, а в анимации `scale`, также меняется, но я не хочу переделывать анимацию.

Comment: Отзеркаль `GameObject` на уровень выше в иерархии, на котором скин и который не подвержен анимации.

Answer (score 1):

Отзеркалить GameObject на уровень выше в иерархии, на котором скин и который не подвержен анимации.